# PHP generating invalid strings

Tags: php, validation, multibyte

There's a lot of implementations for generating random strings that start with a string of allowable characters to pick from.  I want to do the reverse and provide an alphabet of characters to *exclude* (all others being allowed).

The purpose of this is to test rejecting invalid form input so it does not need to be cryptographically secure, just sufficiently random.  I could enumerate bunch of invalid entries but risk missing something.  Not looking to test everything in one go - each test run could generate a handful of invalid strings to assert, and over time cover more of the full gamut.

Something like below where `$valid` contains allowable characters to exclude.  Not sure if there's a faster/easier way to do this.

```php
function randomInvalidChar($valid = '') {
    do {
        $ord = mt_rand(0, 1112063);            // size of utf-8 character set
        $char = mb_chr($ord, 'UTF-8');
        $isValid = mb_strpos($valid, $char);
    } while ( $isValid !== false );

    return $char;
}

$random_string = randomInvalidChar('1234567890.+-*/^');

// => "Ȕ"
```

Comment: Ok, all very interesting, but do you have a question? The phrase "if it aint broke, dont fix it comes to mind"

Comment: +1 to @RiggsFolly, though the question seems to be "is there a faster/easier way to do this?". But if this is working as intended, then I suspect this would fit better on code review SE or something, not SO. That being said, if your invalid list is small, this is probably fine because it will likely only iterate a few times before finding an invalid character.

Comment: code seems abit verbose when you could pipe funcs https://3v4l.org/d16da, also you could use a generator https://3v4l.org/3MrIU but depending on use case might not be worth the overhead

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Wasn't sure if there was more of a built-in method.  Also I posted it here given the prevalence of random string generation questions.